# Forced to use private phone for company "Emergency Alert Notification System"

Tags: united-states, phone, personal-property

I would like to either opt-out of a company "Emergency Alert Notification System", or at least use my work phone to receive the notifications from it, but have been told that isn't an option by our IT department. Can a company force you to use a personal phone for work purposes, when you have a company provided phone that is effectively the same?

When I say effectively the same, I mean it is also a mobile phone. It's a different model from my personal, but identical in capabilities.

Comment: If you have a company-provided phone, probably that phone number is automatically entered into the system for company alerts. Now, it will be inconvenient if the company sends an alert at 2:00 AM, and both your personal and company-provided phone will "RING OUT LOUD" at the same time... :-)

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Exactly, both is excessive and I'd like to keep a clear distinction between my home life and work life.

Comment: I don't see how an automated system would conceptually be any different from a manager ringing you to tell you some important urgent information. If that is illegal, you have your answer.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I'm not worried about getting the notification or not (I mean, I'd prefer to opt out, but also happy to have it on my work phone). The real question is why am I required to use a personal phone instead of one they provide if both are effectively the same. I'll edit the question again to hopefully clarify

Comment: Have you asked what types of alerts they would send through this system and who in the company would make the decision to send such an alert? That may be a good starting point. Once you know that, would you be certain that you would have your company phone on you when you may need to receive those notifications?

Comment: A company can't force you to do anything. You're free to resign any time you like. If it were me, I'd ask what kind of alerts are going to be sent, and why they can't send those to the company provided phone. Then I'd make my decision based on that information. Personally, I bristle at this kind of stuff. If you want me to use my personal resources for company related business, then you ought to be paying me for the use of said personal resources. I'm not obligated to grant my company permission to any of my personal resources, equipment, etc.

Comment: @joeqwerty "A company can't force you to do anything. You're free to resign any time you like." Good call. I really should have made this a question in Law SE using the "force" language, I actually explicitly asked about legality originally. Given the nature of the question it actually seems ill suited here. I'm not particularly looking for advice on how to move forward, but to understand how societal structures(i.e. law, nationally or locally) either allow for or disallow this. Thanks for some good follow up questions either way.

Comment: @tcooper it's not an assumption, you've mentioned in your own comments you don't care about receiving the notifications. ("I'm not worried about receiving the notifications or not") you might have legitimate reasons for this. But you should also understand, it would be a silly thing to raise an issue over. And the reason I'm mentioning it this way is it seems you don't realize that... Also, you mention your interested in knowing specifically if there's a law on it... Why is that? If there were, would you drop $3k suing over it? It's trivial, yet you care this much.... Why?

Comment: Regarding whether the company can force you to do it by the way... It would be rather easy for them to do that. They put it into their employee policies, and require you agree to them as a condition of working.... There is no law in the US at least barring this, so then they would just point to the policy and say if you don't do it you're in breach of the employee policies..... But again.... What would be the goal? If they say they don't let you do it, you won't change their mind. Rather you'll just taint your reputation at this company by appearing as a problem-creating employee

Comment: @schizoid04 I'm a curious person. This isn't a good use of the comment section. And yes, it is an assumption, and an incorrect one at that. But thanks for your time and input anyway.

Comment: I don't think you understand the definition of assumption. Your own words state it - it's not a thought that was drawn from thin air. But again, that's a great example of creating a problem over something that ultimately does not matter

Comment: @schizoid04 Getting the notifications on a different phone has numerous implications. I don't care to share all of the details here, but yes, you've assumed your perfect understanding of a simple phrase to mean precisely what you'd like it to. I'm only responding to clarify your *assumption* but this will be my last comment in reply, as I just said, this isn't a good use of the comment section. Hope you have a great day.

Comment: When you say work phone do you mean a cell phone or a desk phone? It isn't clear what kind of phone that they provided.

Comment: It’s your phone you have the option of turning it off, even blocking the notifications. Not much the company can do, they can’t enforce you to do anything when it requires your own phone. A company mobile would be better but then they can say keep it on at all times.

Comment: I have tagged your question as "United States", since you implied that. Answers are probably correct for the US, but would be uterly ridiculous for any country with labor laws. So... we want to make sure that people know this is US specific.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I've already said in the comments I regret asking here and am trying to delete it. I wanted to know about social norms, laws, etc that are common in regards to this. I'm probably not going to speak to anyone about this again at my company, except maybe our CISO who handles the system, and is my peer/friend. I'm not looking for "how do I show my employer I can do what I want" as has been assumed already... Clearly my writing implies there's some underlying anger or something... not the perspective this question is coming from.

Answer (score 10):

You should opt in.

These kinds of alert systems are designed to let everyone in a company know about site-affecting events - "Mass shooting," "Office closed due to freeze", and things that are going to be directly relevant to you.  The chance you are going to care about a given Amber Alert is nearly zero; the chance you need to know about an emergency alert specifically about your work site is high.

Legally, the answer differs per locale but in California you can be required to use a personal phone for work and can be terminated if you do not, but the company is required to reimburse you for the proportion of expense that is used for work (Cochran v. Schwan's Home Service, Inc.).  It is similar in most US states though there are nuances around the reimbursement.

Comment: @TCooper "why can't I use my company provided phone for this instead?" The company provided phone is for work purposes, that you use between 9 to 5 and excluding lunch. They may need to reach you outside those times.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It's an iphone that's with me all the time. Not a concern. Obviously my desk phone isn't a suitable option though.

Comment: @TCooper Not everyone carries their work phone with them at all times. Some people will only turn it on when they get intimate the office, or if it's used for on call, only turn it on when they are on call.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Some people only carry their personal phones with them outside the home, or leave them off for days at a time. I don't see your point?

Comment: @TCooper They want the best chance of reaching people in an emergency. People are more likely to have their personal phone on them and turned on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126836/discussion-between-tcooper-and-gregory-currie).

Comment: Why does somebody need to know about a workplace shooting if they are not in the workplace?  The alert systems for my work notify me of every storm alert for my area.

Comment: @Donald They may be heading into work, or at lunch, or not at their desk where their work phone may be, or any number of scenarios.

Comment: Nice edit on the legality, I certainly don't think this is a use case where reimbursement makes any sense: "Okay, we sent out an emergency alert, please provide your total phone usage over the month so we can calculate what percent this one message cost and send you 1-3 cents!" hahah - but good information nonetheless.